# how to copy values from certain time periods to replace NAs after outer join in R?

Tags: r, join, merge, outer-join, nas

My data.frame_1 goes from 2017-01-01 up until 2020-10-01 and it has info every quarter, as per:

```
DATE          CLINIC_ID    NR_INDIVIDUALS    REGION_ID   TOTAL_NR_INDIVIDUALS     AVERAGE_INDEX
2017-01-01    A11          3                 A           100                      3
2017-01-01    A11          10                B           100                      3
2017-01-01    A12          14                C           130                      4
2017-01-01    A13          5                 D           110                      5
                        ....
2017-04-01    A11          2                 A           96                       4
2017-04-01    A11          9                 B           96                       4
2017-04-01    A12          13                C           100                      4
2017-04-01    A13          5                 D           105                      7
                        ....
2017-07-01    A11          2                 A           89                       4
2017-07-01    A11          8                 B           89                       4
2017-07-01    A12          14                C           105                      5
2017-07-01    A13          5                 D           90                       7
                        ....
2020-10-01    A11          6                 A           97                       4
2020-10-01    A11          14                B           97                       4
2020-10-01    A12          15                C           90                       6
2020-10-01    A13          3                 D           92                       7
```

My data.frame_2 only has info for 2 time periods (2019-09-01 and 2020-05-01), as per:

```
DATE          REGION_ID       CONNECTIVITY      PERCENTAGE
2019-09-01    A               0<2Mbit/s         3
2019-09-01    A               2<5Mbit/s         4
2019-09-01    A               5<10Mbit/s        13
2019-09-01    A               10<30Mbit/s       60
2019-09-01    A               30<300Mbit/s      10
2019-09-01    A               >=300Mbit/s       10
                        ....
2020-05-01    A               0<2Mbit/s         3
2020-05-01    A               2<5Mbit/s         4
2020-05-01    A               5<10Mbit/s        3
2020-05-01    A               10<30Mbit/s       25
2020-05-01    A               30<300Mbit/s      35
2020-05-01    A               >=300Mbit/s       30
```

I am doing an outer join:

```
data.frame_3 <- merge(x = data.frame_1, y = data.frame_2, by = c("DATE","REGION_CODE"), all = TRUE)
```

**QUESTION1:** Naturally I get NAs for `CONNECTIVITY` and `PERCENTAGE` for all `DATE` in data.frame_1. I would like to fill in the values of `CONNECTIVITY` and `PERCENTAGE` for all months in 2019 with values from 2019-09-01 and in 2020 with values from 2020-05-01. How can I do this?

In a different situation, I have data.frame_4, as per:

```
DATE          CLINIC_ID   TOTAL_NR_INDIVIDUALS   AVERAGE_AGE   
2017-01-01    A11         100                    40
2017-01-01    A11         100                    40
2017-01-01    A12         130                    44
2017-01-01    A13         110                    43
                        ....
2017-02-01    A11         96                     41
2017-02-01    A11         96                     41
2017-02-01    A12         100                    43
2017-02-01    A13         105                    43
                        ....
2017-03-01    A11         89                     41
2017-03-01    A11         89                     41
2017-03-01    A12         105                    42
2017-03-01    A13         90                     42
                        ....
2020-10-01    A11         97                     42
2020-10-01    A11         97                     42
2020-10-01    A12         90                     43
2020-10-01    A13         92                     43
```

I am doing an outer join:

```
data.frame_5 <- merge(x = data.frame_1, y = data.frame_4, by = c("DATE","CLINIC_ID"), all = TRUE)
```

**QUESTION2**: I would like to copy values from `AVERAGE_INDEX` (and other columns in data.frame_1) on 2017-04-01 to observations under 2017-03-01 and 2017-02-01; from 2017-07-01 to observations under 2017-06-01 and 2017-05-01, and so on. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please next time provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here I created something minimal for you.

```r
# question1 ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(lubridate)
date <- as_date("2017-01-01")+months(0:35)
values <- c(1:36)
df <- data.frame(date, values)
# question 1: replace all 2019 values with May values
df$newvalue <- ifelse(year(df$date)==2019, df$value[df$date=="2019-05-01"], df$values)
tail(df, 10)
#>          date values newvalue
#> 27 2019-03-01     27       29
#> 28 2019-04-01     28       29
#> 29 2019-05-01     29       29
#> 30 2019-06-01     30       29
#> 31 2019-07-01     31       29
#> 32 2019-08-01     32       29
#> 33 2019-09-01     33       29
#> 34 2019-10-01     34       29
#> 35 2019-11-01     35       29
#> 36 2019-12-01     36       29
#as you can see the newvalues are correctly using May data for 2019


# question 2: replacing the values of months 3 and 2 by 4 --------
# define the correct months to replace for each row
df$refdate <- ifelse(month(df$date) %in% c(2,3), (paste(year(df$date), "04", "01", sep="-")), as.character(df$date))
df$refdate <- ifelse(month(df$refdate) %in% c(5,6), (paste(year(df$date), "07", "01", sep="-")), as.character(df$refdate))
df$refdate <- as_date(df$refdate)
df$result <- df$values[match(df$refdate, df$date)]
# > head(df[,c("date", "refdate", "result")],8)
# date    refdate result
# 1 2017-01-01 2017-01-01      1
# 2 2017-02-01 2017-04-01      4
# 3 2017-03-01 2017-04-01      4
# 4 2017-04-01 2017-04-01      4
# 5 2017-05-01 2017-07-01      7
# 6 2017-06-01 2017-07-01      7
# 7 2017-07-01 2017-07-01      7
# 8 2017-08-01 2017-08-01      8

# as you can see here feb and march were replaced by april values, 
# may, june replaced by July
```

This way, you can avoid any explicit loop using the very useful function `match`. I try to always rely on this function before making loops of any kind.

Comment: thanks v much @CatalystRPA for suggesting this and apologies for the delay. Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work. For example, in question 2, I don't have those months in between (2017-02-01) and (2017-03-01) in my data.frame_1 so I cannot use 'ifelse(month(df$date) %in% c(2,3)' because these months are not there. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: okay, so if these months are missing you want to insert new rows with the same `values` as April? Basically you want to check if all the months are there then fill in the missing ones right?

Comment: Yes, correct. For Feb and March same values as April, then for May and June same values as July, and so on. Thank you

Comment: Also, if there is a value for you column 'result' in month Feb (because there are some instances where I actually have Feb there) I do not want to replace that value. I only want to replace NAs. Do you have any ideas on how to do this? Thank you